# Problem with jQuery TableSorter's custom parser

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery.tablesorter.addParser({
            id: "commaDigit",
            is: function(s) {
                return false;
            },
            format: function(s) {
                var stripped = s.replace("%","")
                     .replace(/€/g, '')
                     .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"")
                     .replace(",", "")
                     .replace(".", "");
                console.log(s + " -> " + stripped);
                return jQuery.tablesorter.formatFloat(stripped);
            },
            type: "numeric"
        });         

        $("#repStatiOttica").tablesorter({widgets: ['zebra']});

    });
</script>
```

Some of my markup:

```
...
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="{sorter: 'text'}"><b>Stato</b></th>
        <th><b>Ordini</b></th>
                <th class="{sorter: 'commaDigit'}"><b>Ordini %</b></th>
...
```

Text and integers (first and second column) sort correctly.

I tried this parser aiming to parse series of numbers like that:

"23,19%" ; "6,89%" ; "0,50%"

or

"€ 6.240,44" ; "€ 15.000,25" ; "€ 100,00"

Can you help me adapt my parser to my case?

Please answer only with tested solutions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but markup-style assignment of the sorters does not work. Solved using "headers" tablesorter config property.

Comment: To answer your question, `{sorter: 'text'}` only works if you include the metadata plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the jquery metadata plugin for parser metadata to work correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Well, actualy you doing everything good, only thing, that TableSorter have to get `int` values. So when parse values, you should use `parseInt` function for actual integer value.

`return parseInt(stripped);`

Comment: completely wrong answer, the parser doesn't work: inside the "is:" function "return false" => never works / fires; "return true" => fires always, event for unrequested columns; sorting doesn't work right for € values!